# compiler errors when importing project tango SDK to unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

As you can see in the photo below, unity is giving me error for importing tango sdk. i downloaded the unity5 version of sdk from google tango's website and my unity is also a version 5. it's 32 bit however (to work well with vuforia)

I'm not sure how to fix it. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyRwi.png)

Comment: I think you just need to switch your project to Android platform. Should get fixed...

Comment: @NikaKasradze didn't work

Comment: all right then double click that error, select the missing symbol and copy it. ctrl+shift+f to search the whole solution and paste. It should be declared somewhere in the code but either is blocked by preprocessor directive such as #if or its namespace is not imported, or something similar... Just see where it is declared.

Comment: @NikaKasradze couldn't find it anywhere so i just declared it up there object m_emulationTexIdCaptureTextures = null; 
but, now i get new errors :( I'm super new to C# and VS. I'm super lost right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just commented out the lines causing issue... and it works fine for now. but here's the actual solution:
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/pull/50/files